# Bootstrap Modal Form not submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form in my modal which is not working whenever I click the submit button. Nothing happens.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="subModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter your email for updates!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="subscribe.php" method="POST" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="mail@mail.com" required name="email">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Subscribe!">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrapped the submit button also around my form. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You missed your form method know ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "justid" }))
{ 
//your code
}
```